# Stack and concatenate dataframes, with given index level and sorting order

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to reshape and concat simple dataframes, with same index and columns, into a one larger dataframe. 
Say for example i have two datasets, one measuring t's:

```
In [8]: df1
Out[8]: 
       z    a    k
2010  t0   t1   t2
2011  t3   t4   t5
2012  t6   t7   t8
2013  t9  t10  t11
```

and another measuring p's:

```
In [10]: df2
Out[10]: 
       z    a    k
2010  p0   p1   p2
2011  p3   p4   p5
2012  p6   p7   p8
2013  p9  p10  p11
```

and I want to create this dataframe:

```
    ...: df3
Out[11]: 
               t's    p's
stats dates          
z     2010   NaN  NaN
      2011   NaN  NaN
      2012   NaN  NaN
      2013   NaN  NaN
a     2010   NaN  NaN
      2011   NaN  NaN
      2012   NaN  NaN
      2013   NaN  NaN
k     2010   NaN  NaN
      2011   NaN  NaN
      2012   NaN  NaN
      2013   NaN  NaN
```

with obviously the corresponding data for t's and p's. 
I've tried various .stack() with .swaplevel() and then concatenate along axis 1, but I always end up using .sort_index(), which does not preserve the order 'zak'. Any idea how to efficiently perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) of both `DataFrame`s, last set index names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1.unstack(), 
                df2.unstack()], axis=1, keys=('t\'s','p\'s')).rename_axis(['stats','dates'])
print (df)
             t's  p's
stats dates          
z     2010    t0   p0
      2011    t3   p3
      2012    t6   p6
      2013    t9   p9
a     2010    t1   p1
      2011    t4   p4
      2012    t7   p7
      2013   t10  p10
k     2010    t2   p2
      2011    t5   p5
      2012    t8   p8
      2013   t11  p11
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed `stack` and `swaplevel`, but you need some extras:

```
(df1.stack().to_frame(name='t\'s')
    .join(df2.stack().to_frame(name='p\'s'))
    .swaplevel(0,1)
    .sort_index()
)
```

Output:

```
        t's  p's
a 2010   t1   p1
  2011   t4   p4
  2012   t7   p7
  2013  t10  p10
k 2010   t2   p2
  2011   t5   p5
  2012   t8   p8
  2013  t11  p11
z 2010   t0   p0
  2011   t3   p3
  2012   t6   p6
  2013   t9   p9
```